# Gridview SortExpression with 2 fields

Tags: gridview, sorting, viewstate, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a GridView that get's its datasource from a complex object.
So I'm doing the Sorting & Paging in the code behind.

```
<asp:GridView ID="SystemsDetailList" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="gridView_Sorting">
```

For an important title column I have a SortExpression with 2 fields:

```
SortExpression="FunctionalAreaDisplayCode, EswbsDisplayCode"
```

This in the code behind:

```
protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    BindSystemList(e.SortExpression, sortOrder);
}

public string sortOrder
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString() == "desc")
            ViewState["sortOrder"] = "asc";

        else
            ViewState["sortOrder"] = "desc";

        return ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["sortOrder"] = value;
    }
}
```

For some reason it will keep "FunctionalAreaDisplayCode" always sorted ASC but the EswbsDisplayCode works fine as it flips between ASC and DESC correctly.

and tips here?

thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you saying that it should flip between (FunctionalAreaDisplayCode asc, EswbsDisplayCode asc) and  (FunctionalAreaDisplayCode desc, EswbsDisplayCode desc)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's creating an SQL `ORDER BY` clause by simply appending the Sort order to the sort expression. So you will have:

```
FunctionalAreaDisplayCode, EswbsDisplayCode asc
```

and

```
FunctionalAreaDisplayCode, EswbsDisplayCode desc
```

which are interpreted by SQL (or whatever is doing the sorting) as:

```
FunctionalAreaDisplayCode asc, EswbsDisplayCode asc
```

and

```
FunctionalAreaDisplayCode asc, EswbsDisplayCode desc
```

See [this ORDER BY tutorial](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-order-by-sql-tutorial/) :

> It’s important to remember that whenever you are ordering by more than one column, you 
>   need to specify ASC and/or DESC after each column

Hugh